# How to deal with two cases

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get the image url from the meta using a regex like this one:

```
(?s)<meta property="og:image" content="(.*?)" \/>
```

It works fine when the URL has the following:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://the_image.jpg" />
```

but sometimes this property is in the form:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://the_image.jpg">
```

so, the result is a disaster.

I'm a little confused about what should I do for adapt the regex for both cases.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the last part an optional non capturing group:

```
(?s)<meta property="og:image" content="(.*?)"(?: \/)?>
                                             ^^^^^^^^
```

See a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fs%29%3cmeta+property%3d%22og%3aimage%22+content%3d%22%28.*%3f%29%22%28%3f%3a+%5c%2f%29%3f%3e&i=%3cmeta+property%3d%22og%3aimage%22+content%3d%22https%3a%2f%2fthe_image.jpg%22+%2f%3e%0d%0a%3cmeta+property%3d%22og%3aimage%22+content%3d%22https%3a%2f%2fthe_image.jpg%22%3e)

Perhaps you might also update `(.*?)` to use a negated character class `([^"]*)`

Comment: Hi, the solution supplied works like a charm!! Thanks.